# PHP cURL with XML Not Working

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, html-entities

I'm trying to have use cURL to send an API call to idibu (a job board company in the UK). I've successfully made the call with their test information that they provide. You can see that here (I've edited and removed the hash key but in the actual code it's there):

```
<?php
/**
 * Define POST URL and also payload
 */
define('XML_PAYLOAD', 'xml_text=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cidibu%3E%0D%0A%3Cmethod%3Eadd%3C%2Fmethod%3E%0D%0A%3Cconfig%3E%0D%0A%3Cshow_durations%3Eno%3C%2Fshow_durations%3E%0D%0A%3Ccompletionurl%3Eemail%3C%2Fcompletionurl%3E%0D%0A%3Cadvertcompletionemail%3Ebob%40bob.com%3C%2Fadvertcompletionemail%3E%0D%0A%3Clockboards%3Eyes%3C%2Flockboards%3E%0D%0A%3Credirecturl%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com+%3C%2Fredirecturl%3E%0D%0A%3Cvalidate_level%3Ewarning%3C%2Fvalidate_level%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fconfig%3E%0D%0A%3Cjob%3E%0D%0A%3Ctitle%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BXML+v+3+test%2C+please+ignore+Special+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%80%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%3Creference%3EABC123456789%3C%2Freference%3E%0D%0A%3Cdescription%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B%3Cb%3ESpecial+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+here+euro+%80+%0D%0ABasic+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0ASpecial+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0A%0D%0A+%0D%0A+Special+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0ABasic+Te+%A3+%24+%26+%25+%40+%21+%3F+.+%2C+%3D+%29+%28+%2F+-+%3A+%3B+_+%2B+%27+%22+%27+%80+%0D%0A%0D%0A+%96+%96+%92+%27+%95+++++++%2C+%09%2C+%95+%B7+%93+%94+%D8+%85+%A8+%A6+%27+%3A+%27+%83+%E1+%91+%BA+%A1+%A7+%E9+%D7+%87+%27+%3A+%27+%27+%C7+%BD+%84+h+%AE+%97+%AC+%83+%E1+%99%3C%2Fb%3E%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fdescription%3E%0D%0A%3Csender%3E%0D%0A%3Cname%3ESteve%3C%2Fname%3E%0D%0A%3Clastname%3ERogers%3C%2Flastname%3E%0D%0A%3Cemail%3Etest%40mail.net%3C%2Femail%3E%0D%0A%3Ccompany%3EOne+World+Market%3C%2Fcompany%3E%0D%0A%3Cphone%3E44+%280%29+111-1111111%3C%2Fphone%3E%0D%0A%3Cwww%3Ehttp%3A%2F%2Fuk.idibu.com+%3C%2Fwww%3E%0D%0A%3Ccountry%3EUK%3C%2Fcountry%3E%0D%0A%3Cpostcode%3E020+1111+1111%3C%2Fpostcode%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fsender%3E%0D%0A%3Ccategory+id%3D%2221%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Clocation+id%3D%228%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Csublocation+id%3D%22668%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cjobtype+id%3D%222%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cjob_time%3E2%3C%2Fjob_time%3E%0D%0A%3Cstartdate%3E2011-11-26%3C%2Fstartdate%3E%0D%0A%3Cduration%3EFull+time%3C%2Fduration%3E%0D%0A%3Csalarymin%3E20000%3C%2Fsalarymin%3E%0D%0A%3Csalarymax%3E25000%3C%2Fsalarymax%3E%0D%0A%3Csalaryper+value%3D%22annum%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3CsalaryOverride%3ESalary+override+test+test%3C%2FsalaryOverride%3E%0D%0A%3Ccurrency%3EGBP%3C%2Fcurrency%3E%0D%0A%3Cpublish%3E2011-11-26%3C%2Fpublish%3E%0D%0A%3Cposts%3E%0D%0A%3Cboard+id%3D%22517%22%3E%0D%0A%3Cextrafield+name%3D%22idibudts_cat%22%3E3%3C%2Fextrafield%3E%0D%0A%3Cduration+days%3D%227%22+%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fboard%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fposts%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fjob%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fidibu%3E');
define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://ws.idibu.com/clients/api/REMOTE/V3/[INSERT HASH KEY]');

/**
 * Initialize handle and set options
 */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));

/**
 * Execute the request and also time the transaction
 */
$start = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);

$temp = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
      foreach($v as $k1=>$v1) {
      $temp[$k][$k1] = $v1;
      }
}


$stop = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
$totalTime = $stop - $start;

/**
 * Check for errors
 */
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $result = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    switch($returnCode){
        case 404:
            $result = 'ERROR -> 404 Not Found';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Close the handle
 */
curl_close($ch);

/**
 * Output the results and time
 */
echo 'Total time for request: ' . $totalTime . "\n";
echo $json;  

/**
 * Exit the script
 */
    exit(0);
?>
```

I then decoded the data here: http://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii . And got the full XML written out so it's more easily understandable (and so I can enter my own variables in to be processed. I'd like to POST the XML as it is (in the decoded format) but can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
<?php
/**
 * Define POST URL and also payload
 */
$xml = htmlentities('xml_text=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<idibu>
<method>add</method>
<config>
<show_durations>no</show_durations>
<completionurl>email</completionurl>
<advertcompletionemail>bob@bob.com</advertcompletionemail>
<lockboards>yes</lockboards>
<redirecturl>http://www.google.com </redirecturl>
<validate_level>warning</validate_level>
</config>
<job>
<title><![CDATA[XML v 3 test, please ignore Special £ $ & % @ ! ? . , = ) ( - : ; _ + ]]></title>
<reference>ABC123456789</reference>
<description><![CDATA[<b>Special Te £ $ & % @ ! ? . , = ) ( / - : ; _ +  "  here euro  
Basic Te £ $ & % @ ! ? . , = ) ( / - : ; _ + "   
Special Te £ $ & % @ ! ? . , = ) ( / - : ; _ +  "   


 Special Te £ $ & % @ ! ? . , = ) ( / - : ; _ +  "   
Basic Te £ $ & % @ ! ? . , = ) ( / - : ; _ +  "   

            ,   ,  ·   Ø  ¨ ¦  :   á  º ¡ § é ×   :   Ç ½  h ®  ¬  á </b>]]></description>
<sender>
<name>Steve</name>
<lastname>Rogers</lastname>
<email>test@mail.net</email>
<company>One World Market</company>
<phone>44 (0) 111-1111111</phone>
<www>http://uk.idibu.com </www>
<country>UK</country>
<postcode>020 1111 1111</postcode>
</sender>
<category id="21" />
<location id="8" />
<sublocation id="668" />
<jobtype id="2" />
<job_time>2</job_time>
<startdate>2011-11-26</startdate>
<duration>Full time</duration>
<salarymin>20000</salarymin>
<salarymax>25000</salarymax>
<salaryper value="annum" />
<salaryOverride>Salary override test test</salaryOverride>
<currency>GBP</currency>
<publish>2011-11-26</publish>
<posts>
<board id="517">
<extrafield name="idibudts_cat">3</extrafield>
<duration days="7" />
</board>
</posts>
</job>
</idibu>');

define('XML_PAYLOAD', '$xml');
define('XML_POST_URL', 'http://ws.idibu.com/clients/api/REMOTE/V3/[INSERT HASH KEY]');

/**
 * Initialize handle and set options
 */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, XML_PAYLOAD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));

/**
 * Execute the request and also time the transaction
 */
$start = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json,true);

$temp = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  foreach($v as $k1=>$v1) {
    $temp[$k][$k1] = $v1;
  }
}

$stop = array_sum(explode(' ', microtime()));
$totalTime = $stop - $start;

/**
 * Check for errors
 */
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $result = 'ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    switch($returnCode){
        case 404:
            $result = 'ERROR -> 404 Not Found';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

/**
 * Close the handle
 */
curl_close($ch);

/**
 * Output the results and time
 */
echo 'Total time for request: ' . $totalTime . "\n";
echo $json;  

/**
 * Exit the script
 */
exit(0);
?>
```

I've also tried it without the single quotes around '$xml' when defining it as the XML_PAYLOAD. Both times I get:

```
"error":"The xml payload is missing"
```

When I try it without the htmlentities function, it reads the payload but gives me errors like 'the TITLE tag is missing', etc. which is clearly there. Because of this, I'm figuring I need to do some encode of the information before I cURL it.

Any help getting pointed in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't encode the post body. Also try setting the Content-type header. It should be text/xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using rawurlencode instead of htmlentities, and only on the XML part of the 'payload'. Also, you're defining your constant to the literal text "$xml" by using single quotes around your variable. So replacing those two lines with these should do:

```
$xml = 'xml_text='.rawurlencode('<?xml … </idibu>'); # <-- insert entire XML there

define('XML_PAYLOAD', $xml);
```

Comment: That did it. Amazing. Thank you, I've been wrestling with this last piece of the puzzle for quite a while now. Thanks!